# Which permission governs the "Create Linked Page" option on a Sprint in Jira Agile?

Tags: jira, agile, confluence, jira-agile, greenhopper

We're using Jira Agile in combination with Confluence and I'm seeing that some users do not have the <kbd>Link page</kbd> and <kbd>Create Page</kbd> option in the Linked Pages section of the sprint.

The funny thing is that any confluence page created from confluence itself which is linked to any item in the sprint, is added to the section, so for me it doesn't make much sense to hide the option.

Do I really need to make people a project administrator to use this feature?

The two buttons <kbd>Link page</kbd> and <kbd>Create Page</kbd> only seem to show for project admins. How do I make them available to all people in the Developers group?

[image: Image highlighting the missing buttons for some users]

Comment: Asked the same question over on: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/318525/which-permission-governs-the-create-linked-page-option-on-a-sprint-in-jira-agile

Comment: did you open a feature request Ticket already?

Comment: Yeah. Was told that project admin is what you need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a ticket at Atlassian and they replied with the following:

> According to our article on Getting Agile Ready with Atlassian OnDemand:
>
> JIRA permissions — Your users need to have the following permissions:
>
> - Creating/Linking pages to an epic: Requires 'Edit Issues' permission.
> - **Creating/Linking pages to an sprint/sprint report: Requires 'Project Admin' permissions**
>
> Confluence permissions — Your users need to have the following permissions:
>
> - 'Add Page' permission for the appropriate space, if you want them to create Confluence pages via JIRA Agile.

I feel that Project Admin permissions don't make sense for this feature, especially since a link to the sprint is established by mentioning an issue in a page on Confluence. They're automatically added to the sprint-pages as well.